# SMTP retry interval - Lotus Domino

Tags: smtp, ibm-domino

Our ISP only accepts 5 emails per transmission.  If I do a manual send (route *), then I usually get the error:

```
57 Retry( 2) SMTP  [$Retry MY_ISP.COM] (Push)
Last error: 421 4.4.2 Message submission rate for this client has exceeded the configured limit
Next retry: 14/07/2014 08:46:21 AM
```

The retry interval appears to be 30 minutes after I do a 'route *'.  I would like it to retry again in less time.

I have checked the configuration document Router/SMTP > Restrictions and Controls > Transfer Controls > Initial transfer retry interval - this is set to 15 minutes.

I have asked the ISP if they can change their config to accept more emails but do not expect this to change.  If we send bulk emails then this causes a delay in mail sending.

Can anyone advise:
 - Why the interval is 30 mins instead of 15 mins (as configured)?
 - Can I change it to retry every 5 mins?
 - Any pearls of wisdom?

Comment: Stop using them as a relay? You have a fully functional email server, why would you want your outgoing email to be dependent on your ISP?

Comment: That's a really good question. The bad answer is because we have always used a relay?!?  I have added an entry for DNSServer in the ini file and will bounce the server this evening to see if that does the trick.  Thanks @joeqwerty

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but what I've done in the past is set up a program document to do a 'route *' every 5 minutes.

Comment: The issue here was my ISP.  They were throttling how many emails could be transferred as they were doing an upgrade. Once the upgrade was complete then all 600 emails were transferred in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, Domino router will perform the first attempt after an unsuccessful transfer/delivery, two times of the initial retry value. Here is the detailed algorithm:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21089949

So lowering this value should help.

You cannot limit the number of messages in a single session for Domino. There is a [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21496135) about it. I'm sure making an official feature request would be helpful about it.

Another way would be using an intermediate SMTP server (of course one with this capability) between you and the ISP. Domino can be configured to relay on this SMTP server and it might deliver the message.

Setting up a program document would be helpful as well. To do that, you should set program name as "`nserver`" and command line as `-c "route *"`

Comment: Additional to the information above you should then make sure that you do not reject mails after one day. So it might be that you are sending so many emails over your ISP that you couldn´t clean your mail queue in arround a day. This can be configured via [MailTimeout](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/20-smtp_configuration/111-mailtimeout.html). But please do not set a value higher then 2-3 days. Otherwise the user will get undelivered mail notifications for non existing emails 2-3 days AFTER they send the email. I personally think 2 days is OK for you.